# Does Elastic Search query aggregation has limit to upto what it can process or aggregate?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

Hello Community I am fairly new to elastic search and have stumbled upon this issue.
My Elastic Search Application requires aggregation of data to get top hits. The query is working perfectly on almost all use cases and we are getting the values in buckets. But for some cases in which the field on which the aggregation is being performed has a very long text field is not giving the desired results the aggregation is not happening and we are getting buckets as an empty array. So my question is that is there a case that Elastic Search aggregation has a size limit that it cannot aggregate very long text fields?

Comment: it always helps to see some concrete example (data, mapping, query)

Comment: Hey thanks for mentioning the mapping part cannot mention the actual mapping due to it being company code. but as per you comment I looked into the mapping once more and found that ignore_above was mentioned in it which was causing my long string to be ignored.